# dpdk l2fwd-nv: Match error CPU and GPU pointers

Tags: dpdk

I run l2fwd-nv with next command:
./l2fwdnv -l 0-3 -n 8 -a 07:00.0,txq_inline_max=0 -- m 1 -w 2 -b 64 -p 1 -v 0 z 0

Program output:

```
************ L2FWD-NV ************

EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: WARNING! Base virtual address hint (0x100a96000 != 0x7f3b1fe00000) not respected!
EAL:    This may cause issues with mapping memory into secondary processes
EAL: WARNING! Base virtual address hint (0x1016f7000 != 0x7f371fc00000) not respected!
EAL:    This may cause issues with mapping memory into secondary processes
EAL: WARNING! Base virtual address hint (0x102358000 != 0x7f331fa00000) not respected!
EAL:    This may cause issues with mapping memory into secondary processes
EAL: WARNING! Base virtual address hint (0x102fb9000 != 0x7f2f1f800000) not respected!
EAL:    This may cause issues with mapping memory into secondary processes
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL: Probe PCI driver: mlx5_pci (15b3:1017) device: 0000:07:00.0 (socket 0)
common_mlx5: RTE_MEM is selected.
mlx5_pci: Size 0xFFFF is not power of 2, will be aligned to 0x10000.
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created

Device driver name in use: mlx5_pci... 
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: GPU pointer does not match CPU pointer pDev=0x2030c0000 pBuf=0x7f3b20400000
```

What is the error?

ps: https://github.com/NVIDIA/l2fwd-nv

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually running with `-m 1` on the last version of `l2fwd-nv` ? The **device memory path** enabled with `-m 1`, should work in your case. In your question, you lack the `-` of `-m`, is it only a typo ?

Your error comes from the **host pinned memory** path, which is according to the documentation enabled with `-m 0`. This path allocates memory on the CPU, and allows the GPU to access it using [`cudaHostGetDevicePointer`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gc00502b44e5f1bdc0b424487ebb08db0).

I don't know why, but `l2fwd-nv` requires the device pointer returned by `cudaGetHostPointer` to be equal to the initial host pointer. This is the case when your GPU has the attribute `cudaDevAttrCanUseHostPointerForRegisteredMem`. In your case, it looks like your GPU does not have this attribute.